# How to replace each value in struct array

Tags: c, arduino

I'm trying to replace each value in a struct array, seems the code works, but the result is all the elements in the struct array changed to be same, please help.

```
typedef struct { 
    char* name;
    char* mac;
} objThing;

objThing arrayThings[] {
    {"a", ""},
    {"b", ""},
    {"c", ""}
};

void updateMAC()
{
    for (uint8_t t = 0; t < sizeof(arrayThings)/sizeof(objThing); t++)
    {
        char* name = arrayThings[t].name;
        char* mac = arrayThings[t].mac;
        char* new_mac = string2char(MAC_ADDRESS);
        char* new_thing = CombineChars(name, new_mac);
        arrayThings[t].thing = new_thing;
    }
}

char* CombineChars(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    static char strOut[256];
    if((strlen(str1) + strlen(str2)) < 256)
    sprintf(strOut, "%s-%s", str1, str2);
    return strOut;
}
```

I expect the output is:

```
"a", "a-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"b", "b-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"c", "c-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

but the actual output is:

```
"c", "c-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"c", "c-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"c", "c-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: `static char strOut[256];` Since that is static, every pointer will point to it. You could use `new` but that is often frowned upon in a system like the Arduino. You could just make all the char pointers arrays instead. Or use the Arduino `String` class.

Comment: Also, `arrayThings[t].thing = new_thing;` Where does the `thing` member come from?

Comment: Note that `strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) < 256` is not enough to protect against buffer overflow of `strOut`. Don't forget the extra character `'-'` you add in between, *and* the null string terminator.

Comment: Sorry,  should be: char* char_mac = string2char(MAC_ADDRESS);
char* new_mac = CombineChars(name,  char_mac);        arrayThings[t].mac = new_mac;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a `static` variable. This makes every `arrayThings[t].mac` point to it. A couple fixes.

Use `new` (Arduino IDE uses C++ by default. If you are using C, use `malloc()`):

```c++
char* CombineChars(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    char *strOut = new char[strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 2];
    ....
```

And don't forget to `delete` (or `free()`). However calling `new` too often on an Arduino can fragment the heap, so it should be used sparingly.

Another option is to make your structs have arrays. This avoids `new/delete` altogether:

```
typedef struct { 
    char name[256];
    char mac[256];
} objThing;

bool CombineChars(char *str1, char *str2, char *dest, size_t dest_size)
{
    // Ok to be static. Just a temp buffer
    static char strOut[256];
    size_t required_space = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 2;
    if (required_space <= sizeof(strOut) && required_space <= dest_size) {
        sprintf(strOut, "%s-%s", str1, str2);
        strcpy(dest, strOut);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or just use Arduino [Strings](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/):

```
typedef struct { 
    String name;
    String mac;
} objThing;


String separator = "-";
for (uint8_t t = 0; t < sizeof(arrayThings)/sizeof(objThing); t++)
{
    char* new_mac = string2char(MAC_ADDRESS);
    arrayThings[t].mac = arrayThings[t].name + separator + new_mac;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a basic Arduino (e.g. Uno with 2kB RAM), you should be careful with String objects and the new operator. Providing 256 byte for every text isn't a solution, neither.

A MAC address has a fixed size (6 byte, not a text of random length). For the name, you should restrict your project to a reasonable text length, and provide that memory directly at compile time.

And you should avoid changing texts (especially enlarging them) at runtime, if ever possible. I don't see the benefit of your CombineChars() function. (You might have a print helper, which produces such an output when required)